# in the servlet. is there a default PageContext object referred by the keyword "this"

Tags: java, servlets

i'm new to Java Web development and
in my book i find this code in a Servlet class.

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,java.io.IOException
    {  ...
            ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
       ...



}
```

As far as I know `getServletConfig()` is a method of `PageContext` class.
and in the code above there are no object invoke the method.
so there must  (this.) has been omitted.

Q1:so the keyword "this" refer to a object of PageContext class?

and from java perspect, this is a reference to a object for the enclosing
class.in the situation is the object of Servlet.

Q2:so the `PageContext` object=Servlet object?

Comment: Actually, `getServletConfig` is a method of `javax.servlet.GenericServlet`, of which this `HttpServlet` extends.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: No. Explanation: `this` refers to the current object, an instance of the class where your code is runnning. `this` is not pointing to a `PageContext` class (or rather an object instance of `PageContext`) or any inherited class.

Even though the `extends` part is not visible in your code, you most likely extending `HttpServlet` or at least another class extending `HttpServlet`, which then gives you access to all methods (with the correct visibility, `public`or `protected`) in `HttpServlet` and the classes `HttpServlet` extends, including `GenericServlet` where you will also find the `getServletConfig()` method (as Zircon pointed out in his comment). The `getServletConfig()` method will give you an instance of the `ServletConfig` class for this Servlet.

Q2: No, as explained in my answer of Q1. `getServletConfig()` is part of more classes than `GenericServlet`, including `PageContext` so using `getServletConfig()` there you are able to get a `ServletConfig` object for that page context, but it does not mean a `PageContext` object is the same as a Servlet object.